# OOP get this key value of object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, this

So close to nailing this but falling at the last hurdle... Need some clarification.

Basically, I want to load in the array value of a key in a given object as a variable, if other variable strings match.

Perhaps it's better if I give it some context:

**js:**

```
var ArraysObject = {
    "new" : [
        "http://productPageBanners/UK/2new/c0bkn201001u0000.jpg",
        "http://productPageBanners/UK/2new/h0ihd60100000001.jpg",
        "http://productPageBanners/UK/2new/l0flj20100000001.jpg",
        "http://productPageBanners/UK/2new/m0lrt60100000001.jpg",
        "http://productPageBanners/UK/2new/p0gps50106000001.jpg"
    ],
    "knives" : [
        "http://productPageBanners/UK/3aknives/c0bkn201001u0000.jpg",
        "http://productPageBanners/UK/3aknives/n01pl20100000001.jpg"
    ]
};

var url = jQuery(location).attr('href'); // get the current url, outputs URL
var icatRef = url.split("/")[4]; // capture the icatRef from url, outputs ==>"knives"

// Get properties on the object ArraysObject as an array
var icatTitlesInObject = Object.keys(ArraysObject); // outputs the keys in object, i.e ==> ["new","knives"]
```

Then I want to check that if the indexOf that array is equal to the icatRef (pulled from the URL), then create a new variable which stores the relevant array from the correct key.

Something like:

```
if (icatsArray.indexOf() == icatRef) {
    var currentarraytorandomise = ArraysObject.keys.this};
// if "knives" is the icatRef then currentarraytorandomise ==> [
//     "http://productPageBanners/UK/3aknives/c0bkn201001u0000.jpg",
//     "http://productPageBanners/UK/3aknives/n01pl20100000001.jpg"
// ]
```

However that last bit is wrong because `currentarraytorandomise` is undefined.

I hope that's clear! Quite new to OOP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using indexOf incorrectly, try something like this:

```
var currentarraytorandomise, index = icatsArray.indexOf(icatRef);
if (index >= 0) {
  currentarraytorandomise = ArraysObject[icatsArray[index]];
}
```

But you could just try to get the array directly:

```
ArraysObject[icatRef]
```

Without extracting keys or anything. If icatRef doesn't exist, you'll get undefined.

Comment: apologies but that's not what I was going for. 
currentarraytorandomise outputs "knives" here. I need it to output the array of "knives":
currentarraytorandomise; // output ==> ["http://productPageBanners/UK/3aknives/c0bkn201001u0000.jpg","http://productPageBanners/UK/3aknives/n01pl20100000001.jpg"]

Comment: 100% working! brilliant. Any documentation you'd advise reading?

Comment: If you're looking for a JavaScript reference, use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript